# Where does the saved file go in WP7 when used IsolatedStorageFileStream

Tags: c#, file, windows-phone-7, save, isolatedstorage

I am trying to write some text file into isolated storage in WP7 through silverlight code. I want to somehow retrieve the file later and save onto PC. How do I see and get it? Is there some kind of file explorer? Where does it really saved to?

```
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            store.CreateDirectory("MyOutput");

            using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("MyOutput\\data.txt",
                                                  FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                                                  FileAccess.Write,
                                                  store))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use the Isolated Storage Explorer Tool (`ISETool.exe`) which comes with the 7.1 SDK. It's a command line driven tool available in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\IsolatedStorageExplorerTool\` (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\IsolatedStorageExplorerTool` on a 64 bit machine). To interact with your application's Isolated Storage you need to specify if it should connect to a physical device or the emulator as well as the product ID (The GUID specified in your WMAppManifest.xml file). Eg. To download all the files from your emulator to `C:\Foo\` you'd use;

```
ISETool.exe ts xd {ProductID Here} C:\Foo
```

Run `ISETool` without arguments to get help on its exact usage. `ts` here stands for "Take Snapshot", other options are `rs` (Restore Snapshot) and `dir` (list contents). `xd` is "Emulator" and `de` is "Device".

Once you've ran this you can navigate to `C:\Foo` and see the exact contents of the Isolated Storage for your application.

It takes a bit more fiddling than the wp7explorer tool but doesn't require you to link to an assembly or make any code modifications.

Comment: on my machine the path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\IsolatedStorageExplorerTool. I think you forgot the "Explorer"

Comment: No worries. To make it a little less annoying to work with I set up batch files that I can double click on to restore from a directory (with data at various states) and another to dump the current Isolated Storage. Saves me having to hunt down my Product ID every time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [tool](http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/) and after installing `launch` it and run your `application` to find he `saved` file.

If you want how to install and usage you can refer [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/Using-the-Windows-Phone-Isolated-Storage-Explorer-tool)